# Problem with a Product Specification/Data Point that is User Generated (Range may vary)

Tags: gui-design, filter, search-results

This might be a bit hard to explain but hope you can understand me.

I have this current problem. Let's say I have website that is for a database of sports drinks/water with product information about it.

I have an ability for users to measure the PH level themselves at home and submit it to the database. Now I have a problem that is, what if there is multiple submissions on the end of the PH spectrum, I.E one submission at 2 and one submission at 9.

My 2 questions are:

1. When people want search and filter our database by PH submission - what value should I assign to this product with the varying range?
2. I am confused how I could display this as well

Hope this make sense!

Answer (score 1):

**1.** You should avoid users, searching by pH but the results of any other search query can be filtered by pH-range as below.

[image]

**2.** I hope this helps

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev3vN.png)